# Why $dE + dW = C_pdT$?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

$dE$ is Internal Energy

$dW$ is Work Done

$C_p = $ Specific heat at Constant Pressure

In Mayer's Reaction,

They have given the relation $dE + dW = C_p.dT$

But I don't know how they have Derived this Relation.
More information in Image Below :-
[image]

[image]

Comment: They are trying to use that as the definition of the heat capacity at constant pressure.  Actually, the heat capacity at constant pressure is, more correctly defined in terms of the enthalpy E+PV:  $$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P=C_p$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only valid for contant pressure systems as the enthalpy reduces to the heat
$$
ΔH =ΔE + ΔPV =ΔE +PΔV = ΔE + W = Q
$$
or rather in differential form
$$
dH = dE + dW = dQ
$$

Since we know that enthalpy and hence heat can be written as $C_PdT$ for reversible systems (which is true for all isobaric processes which in fact includes our earth)

so
$$
dE + dW = C_P dT
$$
By the way this is just a way of writing first law of thermodynamics for isobaric systems.

Hope i could be of help